# Running specific sampler in jmeter in intervals

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am running my load tests in jmeter. I have **login** service and a **serviceX** which is to be tested. I want **Authtoken** from login service to run serviceX. Token expires every minute. Currently I am having login service in the same thread group and running as much as serviceX. I dont want to continue this. I want to run login service once in every minute in single thread and pass the token to serviceX and ServiceX runs the defined number of threads and time. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use only one token across all threads (virtual users) it makes sense to add another [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 1 thread and infinite number of loops to your Test Plan and add a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to it along with the relevant [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract the token. Also add a [Constant Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) to add pauses between requests, i.e. use `55000` milliseconds as the thread delay value.

Once you have the token you can convert it into a JMeter Property via [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)

In your "main" Thread Group you can read the current token value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

Comment: Thanks much Dmitri. It helps me to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) to achieve this. This controller executes the request inside it only once `per thread` and passes over any other requests under it during further iterations through the test plan.

So, you can put your login service inside the Once Only Controller and `serviceX` outside of the controller. You have to configure your Thread Group accordingly for the iterations or you can wrap up your `serviceX` under [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller).

**Example:**

Say, you want to `login` your first thread only once and then wants to run `serviceX` for 10 times, here is the below test plan sample:

[image]

Remember, as you want to log in once in a minute and once the only controller works on per thread, so you have to use rampup your thread groups accordingly. Suppose, there are 2 threads, and they will log in in a one-minute interval, then the Thread group configurations will be like:

[image]

Now, if you want to run your `serviceX` for 5 times after the 1st thread login, put your `serviceX` under the loop controller scope and the loop count value to `5`

[image]

This is the results of this sample test plan:

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is awesome Jahan. This also helps me to learn how controllers work. Thanks for the time you spent to answer in detail with screenshots.